# How do I remove space between table rows?

Tags: html, html-table, row

I've seen a couple of answers but I can't get it to work. I want to remove the white space between rows so the images in my table basically touch (looks like one whole image).

---

```
<center> <table class="table3">

<tr><img alt="ZE40" src="images/showroom/volkracing.PNG" title=""></tr>

<tr> 
<td><img alt="ZE40" src="images/showroom/ze40.jpg" title=""></td>
<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultratrack.jpg" title=""> </td>
<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultra.jpg" title=""></td>
<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/te37ultral.jpg" title=""></td>
<td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g27.jpg" title=""></td>
 </tr>
</table></center>
```

My CSS:

```
.table3{

border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing: 0;

}
```

Is this the right way to do this? Please note; I have other lists on my website which I do not want to affect.

Comment: Have you tried `img { display: block; }` ?

Comment: That works Beamer, but is there a way to only assign it to that table? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that works then try this to apply just for images in your table:

```
.table3 img{
    display: block;
}
```